# Ember: handle multiple actions in a tag for a component?

Tags: ember.js

I have a component in which I would like to handle the 'mouseEnter' and 'mouseLeave' events using action on the same tag.

Is there a way to do this, other than changing my component to a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
App.MouseTrackingComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['mouseTracker'], 

  mouseEnter: function(){
    console.log("Entered")
  },

  mouseLeave: function(){
    console.log("Left");
  }
});
```

You can then use it in your template as follows:

```
{{ mouse-tracking }}
```

Full example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wipanusagi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Right, and remember that a component is actually a view, but isolated!